# Probability of $X_{n+1}=x$ in a random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I have the following problem regarding random walks:

Given a simple random walk $\{ X_n : n=0,1,2,\dots \} $ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $p+q=1$ show that $$P(X_{n+1}=x) = p P(X_n = x-1 ) + qP(X_n = x+1 )$$

I don't know where to start, it seems intuitive since it is just like the Law of Total Probability. I also have this result to help me: $P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n = i)=\begin{cases} p &  \text{ if }j=i+1 \\ q &  \text{ if } j = i-1\end{cases}$. I don't know how to put it all together, thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe it should be $P(X_{n+1}=x) = p P(X_n = x-1 ) + qP(X_n = x+1 )$.  Use the formula for conditional probability.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in the lhs: $P(X_{n+1}=\color{red}n)$; and the "result" you have looks like the definitions for what $p,q$ are supposed to be: $p$ is the probability that you walk a step towards the right while $q$ is for a step towards the left; now, for a random walk in $\Bbb Z$, you can get to $n$ in a single step only from $n-1$ or $n+1$, with a right or left step respectively. The recurrence relation is then trivial by the rule of product/sum.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas  I think the subscript should not equal the value: do not use $n$ for both of them... $P(X_{n+1}=n)$

Comment: @GEdgar: Ah, good point! Forgot that I used $n$ in the subscript. I personally like it written as $P(X_{n+1}=k)=pP(X_n=k-1)+qP(X_n=k+1)$ (makes me a bit uncomfortable to use $x$ for integer... even if $X$ is used for the rv)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've edited the $X_n = x $ part. Just to be clear, how can I apply the product and sum rules? I'm used to them as sets but I can't get the notation and the combination I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is not much to prove I think.

$p(X_{n+1}=x)=\sum_{a \in Z} p(X_{n+1}=x|X_{n}=a)p(X_{n}=a)$

This is the law of total probability. Now only two conditional probabilities are nonzero in your case, namely $a=x-1$ and $a=x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using characteristic functions. The characteristic function of $X_n$ is
$$\varphi_{X_n}(a)=E[e^{iaX_n}]=E[e^{ia\sum^n Y_k}]=(qe^{-ia}+pe^{ia})^n$$
thanks to IIDness of the increments $(Y_k)_{k \leq n}$. So
$$\begin{aligned}\varphi_{X_{n+1}}(a)&=(qe^{-ia}+pe^{ia})^n(qe^{-ia}+pe^{ia})=\\
&=q(qe^{-ia}+pe^{ia})^ne^{-ia}+p(qe^{-ia}+pe^{ia})^ne^{ia}=\\
&=q\varphi_{X_n}(a)e^{-ia}+p\varphi_{X_n}(a)e^{ia}\end{aligned}$$
By using the shift properties of characteristic functions, if we invert back to $P_{X_n}(k)$ we get
$$P_{X_{n+1}}(k)=qP_{X_{n}}(k+1)+pP_{X_{n}}(k-1)$$

---

To show the shifting property:

$$(2\pi)^{-1}\int \varphi_{X_n}(a)e^{-ia}e^{-iak}da=(2\pi)^{-1}\int \varphi_{X_n}(a)e^{-ia(k+1)}da=P_{X_n}(k+1)$$